# How can I use BarChart to add label of the range of each set of data on the x axis?

Tags: graphics

(*My code:*)

```
DataFirst = {0, -1, 0.5, 1, -4.5, 4.5, -0.5, 6, -4.5, 0, -1.5, 
             1.5, -0.5, 2.5, 0, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -6.5, -3, 2.5, -3, -0.5, 2.5, 
             5, 2.5, -3, -2.5, 1.5, -2, 2, -0.5, 3.5, -2.5, 2.5, -1, 
             1.5, -1, -3.5, 1.5, -1, -1, -2, 5.5, 4, 1.5, -6, -1.5, 0, -1, 2, 4,
             3, -2, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0, -0.5, -1, 2, -5, 2.5, 2.5, 
             7, -2, -2.5, -2.5, 2, -2.5, 4, 2, 4, -5, 1.5, -1.5, 2, -2.5, -3, 
             2, -1, -2.5, 1, 5, 3, -0.5, -2.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 4, -0.5, 
             1, -1, 1.5, 0.5, 2.5};
max = Max[DataFirst];
min = Min[DataFirst];
dx = (max - min)/10;
fi = BinCounts[DataFirst, {min, max, dx}]
BarChart[fi]
```

I want to show the range of each set of data on the x axis.

[image]

for example，`min` to `min+dx`, `min+dx` to `min+2*dx` and so on 
until `min+9 *dx` to `max` *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ChartLabels` is another way, apart from what Nasser suggests, to achieve this:

```
BarChart[fi, 
 ChartLabels -> (Rotate[#, Pi/4] & /@ 
    Table[ToString[x] <> " to " <> ToString[x + dx], {x, min, max, 
      dx}])]
```

[image: barchart]

Answer (score 1):

There could be many possible solutions. Basically you have to design your own labels. For example:

```
lbls = (ToString[#[[1]]] <> " | " <> ToString[#[[2]]]) & /@ 
        Partition[Range[min, max, dx], 2, 1]
```

I am using "|" as separator. Then just

```
BarChart[fi, AspectRatio -> 1/5, ImageSize -> 800, ChartLabels -> lbls, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ChartElementData["GradientRectangle", 
   "ColorScheme" -> "BeachColors", "GradientOrigin" -> Top]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFirst = {0, -1, 0.5, 1, -4.5, 4.5, -0.5, 6, -4.5, 0, -1.5, 
   1.5, -0.5, 2.5, 0, 2, -1, 2, -1, 2, -6.5, -3, 2.5, -3, -0.5, 2.5, 
   5, 2.5, -3, -2.5, 1.5, -2, 2, -0.5, 3.5, -2.5, 2.5, -1, 
   1.5, -1, -3.5, 1.5, -1, -1, -2, 5.5, 4, 1.5, -6, -1.5, 0, -1, 2, 4,
    3, -2, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0, -0.5, -1, 2, -5, 2.5, 2.5, 
   7, -2, -2.5, -2.5, 2, -2.5, 4, 2, 4, -5, 1.5, -1.5, 2, -2.5, -3, 
   2, -1, -2.5, 1, 5, 3, -0.5, -2.5, 0.5, -0.5, 1, 0.5, 4, -0.5, 
   1, -1, 1.5, 0.5, 2.5};
max = Max[DataFirst];
min = Min[DataFirst];
dx = (max - min)/10;
fi = BinCounts[DataFirst, {min, max, dx}]
fi = Table[Labeled[fi[[i]],Style[Rotate[
      Row[{"(", min + (dx*i-1), ",", min + dx*i, ")", Spacer[10]}], 
      90 Degree], 14]], {i, 0, Length[fi]}];

BarChart[fi]
```

[image: the modified picture]

or framed?

[image: Mathematica graphics]